# Extra columns showing up in DataGridView but not showing in SQL

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I am doing a Windows form program with visual studio and have started using LINQ for the first time, I have a database which has been set up in SQL Server and have linked it to my program in visual studio.

I have added a **DataGridView** to my form and put in the following code to load one of the database tables into the DGV in the form load event.

```
  LINQDataClassesDataContext DB = new LINQDataClassesDataContext();
    var test (from s in DB.Student_Courses select s);
    dgvDataTab1.DataSource = test;
```

the table data loads into the DGV but with 2 extra columns on the end "Course" and "Student" https://gyazo.com/212646a0f43c2588d4413bef33b24f5b

But when a run a SQL query on this table in SQL Server those 2 extra columns do not show.

I also noticed under the LINQDataClasses in the solution explorer the Student_Course table has 2 EntityRef which i do not know what they are or how they got their.

Has anyone else come up against this? and if so how to remove them but still be able to add/edit in the DataGridView.

hers a link to my database added with LINQ https://gyazo.com/ae1959f18c4647525036c3070f6a8f07

Kind Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a projection?

```
LINQDataClassesDataContext DB = new LINQDataClassesDataContext();
var test = (from s in DB.Student_Courses select new { SID, CID , Mark } );
dgvDataTab1.DataSource = test;
```

Can you hide those columns?

```
dgvDataTab1.Columns["Course"].Visible = false
dgvDataTab1.Columns["Student"].Visible = false
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reponce, I have tried that one it only shows the 3 columns i want but takes away being able to add/edit in the DataGridView

Comment: Yep cool that has hidden them from view and it seems that I can still add/edit, will try some code now to add/edit and see how that goes. Thank you :)